# openSSL upgrade in apache webserver

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, openssl

we are using apache webserver ver 2.2.3 with open SSL version 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 (linux environment). We are required to upgrade the openSSL to the latest version for security reasons. I have following doubts

1. as per https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20140605.txt, ver 0.9.8  should be upgraded to 0.9.8za. Please let me know if its ok to upgrade to 0.9.8za or we should go for 1.0.1h
2. what is the procedure of upgrading openssl which comes with apache webserver
3. Is it required to regenerate the keys and certificate again

Comment: OpenSSL has a habit of breaking interfaces. You’ll be lucky if you can upgrade at all.

Comment: Thanks for replying. If this is the case then what is the preferred alternative